# How to populate a django form in a POST request with data from an ajax call?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django, django-forms

I'm sending form data via an ajax call after user hits submit button and then handling this request in my views, but the form is empty. How can I populate the form?

This is my code:

My JS file:

```
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');  //getCookie is a csrf_token generator
var form = $(this).closest('form')
$.ajax({
        url: form.attr("action"),
        data: {        // if I change this line to data: form.serialize(), it works fine!
            csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrftoken,
            form: form.serialize(),  
    },
        type: form.attr("method"),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data)
        {
            //Do a bunch of stuff here
        }
})
```

My views:

```
def task_edit(request, pk):
    task = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        task_form = NewTaskForm(request.POST) # This is empty!

    else:
        task_form = NewTaskForm(instance=task) # This for populating the edit modal, works fine!
```

I'm not doing the `data: form.serialize()` because I need to send additional data with the ajax request. How do I get this working?

Comment: How to do you know that `form: form.serialize()` works?

Comment: Because in my views inside the if condition, doing `raise Exception (task_form)` shows form with populated fields.

Comment: That means js form.serialize() doesn't work, it sends the forms actually, but not the populated fields

Comment: Before I try this implementation, I was using `data: form.serialize()` and everything was working fine! I need to send the submit button value along with data now and that's where I'm facing the challenge and need help

Answer (score 2):

You can write as below:-

```
$form_data = $("#idofform").serialize();
```

And then in ajax

```
data : $form_data+'&key=value',
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use services like https://www.formkeep.com to capture form data using AJAX.

This may be a good idea if you are already using a JavaScript framework, you want to add validation logic, or you don't want to redirect the user after they submit the form.

You can submit to FormKeep using a standard AJAX request. To ensure the request does not cause a redirect, be sure to set the Accept header to application/javascript.

Given the following form:

```
<form id="newsletter-signup" action="http://formkeep.com/f/exampletoken" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="utf8" value="✓">
    <input name="email" type="email">
    <input value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Here's an example of how to submit a form with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
   $('#newsletter-signup').submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var formEl = $(this);
var submitButton = $('input[type=submit]', formEl);

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: formEl.prop('action'),
  accept: {
    javascript: 'application/javascript'
  },
  data: formEl.serialize(),
  beforeSend: function() {
    submitButton.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
}).done(function(data) {
  submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
});
});
});
```

That's it. Once your data is securely captured in FormKeep you can easily store it, manage it or connect it with 1000s of other systems like Google Docs and Hubspot and Mailchimp.

Comment: Formkeep may help here, but you haven't actually answered about the part that was asked, which is how to populate the form that was previously submitted by ajax.